# What is the current Apple color pallet?

Tags: color, apple

I have seen the same color pallet used in several of Apple's ads, as well as app icons (e.g., Photos app).

Does anyone know the values for the colors in this pallet?

[image: Apple TV Billboard]

Answer (score 1):

It's not a colour pallette. It's a stylistic variation of the SMPTE color bars: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMPTE_color_bars

Also, you can extract the RGB colors from the photograph you posted, though they won't be the same as the CMYK values used to create the original print due to lighting conditions (colour of sunlight, ambient reflections, shadows, etc).

Comment: 1. As you noted, it's a variation, so why would I be asking for well-known color values? 2. Also as you noted, simply using the dropper on this photo will not give me anything close to the actual values.

Comment: @nipponese How would anyone know the color values besides the designers at Apple? This isn't part of a kit that they would give to developers. Your best bet would be to Google Search the image above to find a web version of the image and use a eye drop.[Apple Color Bars Ad](https://www.google.com/search?q=apple+tv+ad&tbm=isch&tbs=simg:CAQSiQEahgELEKjU2AQaAggIDAsQsIynCBpfCl0IAxIl-Ago_1wi0AkdhtwOBCYIJ9wiCNKEroCuANKI98yKCN4M3oT2-KBowU5A9Etz80tRTAi8yW-ZJwRIWwTcqQzT9D6fN6tVeAeMgXUvt8GAn4ZvvGoQVyAEQIAMMCxCOrv4IGgoKCAgBEgSmkAg1DA&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj83eajgcbKAhVBSCYKHVGDA9IQ2A4IGygB&biw=2554&bih=1209)

Comment: But even with a web version, the values are likely to be different to a degree.

Comment: @AndrewH Often times these values are shared in public PR docs.

Comment: It's an ad, not a corporate identity. While maybe Apple published this info somewhere, it seems highly unlikely. I don't even know if Apple could answer the question as their ad agency likely made it.

Answer (score 1):

This ad is available in an RGB version on YouTube. The video version also has many more frames and colors:

[Apple TV — The Future of Television](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OON2bZdqVzs)

The ad plays with the idea of the TV color bars, but they are not using the standard SMPTE colors.

If you are looking for a single color palate that has a lot of the colors that Apple is favoring right now, the screen captures of an iPhone running iOS 9 or an Apple Watch home screen are pretty good examples.

Note that you don’t need to know the color names or values. You just need to open the screen capture in a second window in your design tool and sample the colors with a picker as you work.